# How to read numbers in python from csv file?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, file-io, numbers

I have a csv file and I have to compute the mean for some of the columns.
That's how I did:

```
file=csv.reader(open('tab.csv','r'))
n=[]
for row in file:
    n.append(row[8])
```

So I have a list of string : n=['','','1.58'...]
How can I convert these to float?
I tried with :

```
n_values=np.array(n)
n_values[n=='']='0'
values=n_values.astype(np.float)
np.mean(values)
```

But the mean is not correct because I should skip the empty strings not counting.
Thank for your help!

Comment: You can use `n.append(float(row[8]))`, but if you have empty values you will need to put that inside a try/except block.

Comment: @Alice What you are actually asking is how to convert string into float. The rest of the stuff in the question is irrelevant

Comment: @OmerDagan: having to make explicit type conversions is a code smell, just use pandas `pd.read.csv()`. The question as stands is fine (hopefully that CSV file has a header)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just cast as you append:

```
 n.append(float(row[8]))
```

If there are empty strings catch those before appending.

```
try:
    n.append(float(row[8]))
except ValueError:
   continue
```

Or you might want to try pandas, in particular [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("in.csv")
print(df["col_name"].mean())
```

Comment: No prob, you're welcome. if you are using numpy and dealing with csv's  I would definitely recommend having a look at pandas.

Comment: I tryed but I got : no module named pandas. Should I install it?

Comment: yes you have to install it.
try installing it with pip

Comment: Or, no, you shouldn't. Pandas is an excellent solution if you want to get into serious data analysis, but serious overkill if all you need is to read some numbers from a file (a huge and complex library of considerable size and with a new and nontrivial learning curve of its own).

Answer (score 19):

Just add quoting:

```
with open('tab.csv', newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    n=[]
    for row in reader:
        n.append(row[8])
```

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) on `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`

Comment: This is the best answer. It perfectly and simply answers the actual question. The other answers go on a tangent to help with calculating the mean rather than dealing with the actual underlying problem: The numbers are being represented by strings.

Comment: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: "'Beta'"`

Comment: @flywire That is correct; you cannot convert an arbitrary string to a number. If you meant to ask what you can do about it, search the error message; that's a massive FAQ. Perhaps also note that the accepted answer solves this (quietly, which is a problem when you end up wondering why it comes up zero or whatever).

Comment: numpy is just crap with csv files. Fortunately python has good csv support.