# Error: Unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, csv, typeerror

I wanted to try doing a dependent two-tailed t-test using Python. Unfortunately I keep getting an error and I don't know how to solve it.

Here is my data.

I have two different CSV - File's:

First: wearable

```
right
0.960, 
1.079, 
1.019, 
1.028, 
1.086, 
1.042, 
0.860, 
1.062, 
1.020, 
1.028, 
1.088, 
1.076, 
0.988, 
1.032, 
1.139, 
1.058, 
1.015, 
1.014, 
1.203, 
1.085, 
0.948, 
1.019, 
1.125, 
1.037, 
1.012, 
1.008,  
1.036, 
1.028, 
0.970, 
1.072, 
1.076, 
0.969, 
0.995, 
1.059, 
0.995
```

and second: Vicon

```
right
1.010, 
1.076, 
1.057, 
1.026, 
1.036, 
0.858, 
0.984, 
1.024, 
0.966, 
1.102, 
1.079, 
1.046, 
0.936, 
0.991, 
1.217, 
1.177, 
1.010, 
1.054, 
1.324, 
1.144,
0.881, 
1.087, 
0.970, 
0.970, 
1.077, 
1.080, 
0.940, 
0.906, 
0.955, 
1.139, 
1.082, 
1.011, 
1.130, 
0.949, 
0.938
```

My task was to do a dependent t-Test.
I tried it this way:

```
vicon_right = pd.read_csv("vicon_right.csv")
tragbar_right = pd.read_csv("wearable_right.csv")
tteste=stats.ttest_rel(tragbar_right['right'],vicon_right['right'])
```

But then I get the error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Could someone please help me solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You data was never parsed into numbers.

Comment: and also you should include the complete TraceBack when asking for help. that makes it easier to focus on where the error comes from

Comment: @rdas You mean the error comes from that? How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537187/how-to-read-numbers-in-python-from-csv-file

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-6e90a821a06d>", line 43, in <module>
    tteste=stats.ttest_rel(wearable_right['right'],vicon_right['right'])

  File "C:\Users\nadin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 4661, in ttest_rel
    d = (a - b).astype(np.float64)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' `

Comment: @rdas The link does not help much. I have already done what it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your data set is not structured properly. Make the following changes:

- Put a `,` after the column header `right`.
- Make sure that there is a space after each `,` as the space indicates pandas to move to the next row. Otherwise, it will create a column with NaN values.

If you do this correctly, then the values will automatically be read as float64 type and you won't have to convert them. The error you get is because the library does some numeric comparison which obviously cannot happen if the input is a string.

See below for an example of a properly structured `Vicon.csv`.

```
right, 
1.010, 
1.076, 
1.057, 
1.026, 
1.036, 
0.858, 
0.984, 
1.024, 
0.966, 
1.102, 
1.079, 
1.046, 
0.936, 
0.991, 
1.217, 
1.177, 
1.010, 
1.054, 
1.324, 
1.144, 
0.881, 
1.087, 
0.970, 
0.970, 
1.077, 
1.080, 
0.940, 
0.906, 
0.955, 
1.139, 
1.082, 
1.011, 
1.130, 
0.949, 
0.938,
```

And when we print it, we can see that the data type is float64. Originally, if you print it with the command `vicon_data['right']`, you will see that the data type is `object`.

```
0     1.010
1     1.076
2     1.057
3     1.026
4     1.036
5     0.858
6     0.984
7     1.024
8     0.966
9     1.102
10    1.079
11    1.046
12    0.936
13    0.991
14    1.217
15    1.177
16    1.010
17    1.054
18    1.324
19    1.144
20    0.881
21    1.087
22    0.970
23    0.970
24    1.077
25    1.080
26    0.940
27    0.906
28    0.955
29    1.139
30    1.082
31    1.011
32    1.130
33    0.949
34    0.938
Name: right, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thats very useful. I will try it. Thank you